# Calculate the frequency of two columns and generating the Frequency in new columns R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a DF with **Patient_ID, Gender, Hospital_ID, and Patient_Condition.**

```
    Demography <- read.table(text="
Pat_ID  Gender  Hospital_ID Condition
P1  M   A434 Normal
P2  F   A232 Average
P3  F   A331 Critical
P4  M   A434 Below_Critical
P5  F   A212 Average
P6  F   A331 Average
P7  F   A212 Critical
P8  F   A434 Average
P9  F   A331 Critical
P10  M   A232 Below_Critical", header=TRUE)
```

What I want is to calculate or generate the frequencey for each Hospital_ID against the frequency by each condition in separate columns. Below is the output DF example.

| Hospital_ID | Hospital_Freq | Average_Freq | Normal_Freq | Critical_Freq | Below_Critical_Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A434 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| A232 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| A331 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| A212 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Try with `base R` `addmargins(table(Demography[, c("Hospital_ID", "Condition")]), 2)`

Comment: Hi, It returns the value of Conditions in the same column, whereas I want them in different columns.

Comment: It is in different columns, though in a table class object. You can convert to data.frame with `as.data.frame.matrix` wrapped over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

Demography |> 
  mutate(Hospital_Freq = n(), .by = Hospital_ID) |> 
  reframe(Hospital_Freq, value = length(Condition), .by = c("Hospital_ID", "Condition")) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Condition, values_from = value, values_fill = 0, values_fn = first, names_glue = "{Condition}_Freq")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  Hospital_ID Hospital_Freq Normal_Freq Average_Freq Critical_Freq
  <chr>               <int>       <int>        <int>         <int>
1 A434                    3           1            1             0
2 A232                    2           0            1             0
3 A331                    3           0            1             2
4 A212                    2           0            1             1
# ℹ 1 more variable: Below_Critical_Freq <int>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `janitor` library is built around a dplyr based frequency table (pivot table) function `tabyl()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)          
Demography |> 
    tabyl(Hospital_ID, Condition) |> 
    adorn_totals("col")

 Hospital_ID Average Below_Critical Critical Normal Total
        A212       1              0        1      0     2
        A232       1              1        0      0     2
        A331       1              0        2      0     3
        A434       1              1        0      1     3
```